# Django save object in database

Tags: python, django

First of all I should mention that I'm new to Python as well as Django.

I have a Django project with an sqlite3 database.
I have created a couple of classes for calculating some physical problems, and I want to access the result of these through my website using forms. My previous approach to this was to change my classes to functions, and create several model fields for my objects.

Then I reached a point where the output of my function was a 2D-array, which I have issues saving in my model. So I decided it would be easier just to store the entire object in the database - then I wouldn't have to change my classes to functions in order to utilize it in Django.

I'm using inputs for my calculations in a form, `a` and `b` below.
Is it possible to store objects in my model?
I have made a hypothetic example, not sure if the code works but hope that you get the point.

```
class Butterfly_model(models.Model):
    a = models.FloatField(verbose_name='a')
    b = models.FloatField(verbose_name='b')
    results = >>>Some_Object_Field<<<
```

my computation script could contain something like this:

```
class Compute:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.X=[]
        self.Y=[]
        for i in range(0,a):
            self.X.append(i)
            self.Y.append(i+b)
```

And my view.py contains following:

```
if form_input.is_valid():
    instance = form_input.save(commit=False)
    instance.results = Compute(instance.a,instance.b)
    instance.save()
```

If not possible, does any of you have a suggestion for how handle calculations and resulting data like this?

Best regards,

Joachim

Comment: Can you claryfy what you want? Do you want to have `X` and `Y` fields on your model, that depend on `a` and `b`?

Comment: I want to create an object in Compute (using Butterfly_models a and b) and store that object in the >>>object field<<< in Butterfly_model, if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably looking for are [model properties](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#model-methods). From anticipating your needs I think you are looking for:

You can add properties to you models that calculate a function. For your case it would be sth like:

```
class Butterfly_model(models.Model):
    a = models.FloatField(verbose_name='a')
    b = models.FloatField(verbose_name='b')

    @property
    def X(self):
        return [i for i in range(0,self.a)]

    @property
    def Y(self):
        return [i+b for i in range(0,self.a)]
```

That way you can access `X` and `Y` for each model instance and do not need to save it in the database (if that is what you want?).

Comment: I'm very fond of that idea actually, the implementation works like a charm. However I guess if the calculations were requiring a lot of iteration, this solution wouldn't be suitable due to computing time.